# How to replicate a floatbuffer in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to replicate a Java FloatBuffer in swift? In the code below you set the floatbuffer position to tell OpenGL which floats in the array are for position and which are for texture coordinates.

```
floatBuffer.position(dataOffset);
glVertexAttribPointer(attributeLocation, componentCount, GL_FLOAT, false, stride, floatBuffer);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(attributeLocation);
floatBuffer.position(0);
```

Comment: In c I believe the equivalent would be myArrayPointer += dataOffset. This doesn't work in swift.

Comment: Have you tried `floatBuffer[dataOffset]`?

Comment: I thought about that, but wouldn't it just return the value in that position?

Comment: If it's expecting a memory address, you could just `&` it.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the code at [iOSSwiftOpenGL](https://github.com/bradley/iOSSwiftOpenGL/blob/master/iOSSwiftOpenGL/OpenGLView.swift) for a sample solution.

The key is creating vertices and indexes in the following way:

```
struct Vertex {
    var Position: (CFloat, CFloat, CFloat)
    var Color: (CFloat, CFloat, CFloat, CFloat)
}

var Vertices = [
    Vertex(Position: (1, -1, 0) , Color: (1, 0, 0, 1)),
    Vertex(Position: (1, 1, 0)  , Color: (0, 1, 0, 1)),
    Vertex(Position: (-1, 1, 0) , Color: (0, 0, 1, 1)),
    Vertex(Position: (-1, -1, 0), Color: (0, 0, 0, 1))
]
```

Comment: That is for vertex buffer objects. I need to also pass the array directly in.

Comment: The code that I referenced has many examples of that: `colorSlotFirstComponent = ConstUnsafePointer<Int>(sizeof(Float) * 3)` and also look at how he uses `glGetAttribLocation`